# Javascript array of objects - filter by uniqueness of specific key, and keep only certain keys

Tags: javascript

I'm sure this question has been asked in some form here before, but I am having trouble finding the right solution. I have an array of objects like this:

```
[
  {id:"124", name:"Joe", lname:"Smith", age:"14"},
  {id:"124", name:"Joe", lname:"Smith", age:"17"},
  {id:"124", name:"Joe", lname:"Smith", age:"21"},
  {id:"128", name:"Tom", lname:"Cans", age:"18"},
  {id:"132", name:"Mik", lname:"Brak", age:"21"}
];
```

and I would like to shorten this array so that it only includes objects with unique `id` keys, as well as only the keys **id, name, lname**. The output I'm going for then is:

```
 [
   {id:"124", name:"Joe", lname:"Smith"},
   {id:"128", name:"Tom", lname:"Cans"},
   {id:"132", name:"Mik", lname:"Brak"}
 ];
```

What I've done so far - I can use the following code snippet to create an array of unique IDs, but that isn't getting me to where I need to go:

```
 let uniqueIDs = [... new Set(mydata.map(val => val.id))];
```

Any help is appreciated!!

Comment: lots of answers coming in quick - will try to address them all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store your array items in an object, indexed by `id`, and skip any which you already have:

```js
var obj = {}
[ {id:"124", name:"Joe", lname:"Smith", age:"14"},
  {id:"124", name:"Joe", lname:"Smith", age:"17"},
  {id:"124", name:"Joe", lname:"Smith", age:"21"},
  {id:"128", name:"Tom", lname:"Cans", age:"18"},
  {id:"132", name:"Mik", lname:"Brak", age:"21"}
].forEach(function(d){
  if ( ! obj[d.id] ) {
    // omit the info you're not interested in
    obj[d.id] = { id: d.id, name: d.name, lname: d.lname } 
  }
})
var uniq = Object.values(obj);
console.log(uniq)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could take a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) of [JSON](http://json.org/) strings and map them by parsing it.

```js
var array = [{ id: "124", name: "Joe", lname: "Smith", age: "14" }, { id: "124", name: "Joe", lname: "Smith", age: "17" }, { id: "124", name: "Joe", lname: "Smith", age: "21" }, { id: "128", name: "Tom", lname: "Cans", age: "18" }, { id: "132", name: "Mik", lname: "Brak", age: "21" }], 
    unique = Array.from(
        new Set(array.map(({ id, name, lname }) => JSON.stringify({ id, name, lname }))),
        JSON.parse
    );

console.log(unique);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

First step is to create a data structure where you can be sure your entries are unique. I like reduce to convert an array to a map.

`const arrayToMap = array.reduce((obj, { id, name, lname}) => ({ ...obj, [id]: { id, name, lname }), {});`

Then you need to build the map to an array by iterating over the keys.

`const mapToArray = Object.keys(arrayToMap).map(key => ({ ...arrayToMap[key] });`

Answer (score 0):

Here's an approach using `Set` and `filter` to remove duplicate `id` keys and `map` to remove the `age` key:

```js
const data = [
  {id: "124", name: "Joe", lname: "Smith", age: "14"},
  {id: "124", name: "Joe", lname: "Smith", age: "17"},
  {id: "124", name: "Joe", lname: "Smith", age: "21"},
  {id: "128", name: "Tom", lname: "Cans", age: "18"},
  {id: "132", name: "Mik", lname: "Brak", age: "21"},
];

const ids = new Set(data.map(e => e.id));

const result = data
  .filter(e => ids.delete(e.id))
  .map(({id, name, lname}) => ({id, name, lname}))
;

console.log(result);
```